# Ansible Loop for One list over another

Tags: ansible

```
    I have two lists
```

[image]

I am trying to iterate over the loop in ansible. I want the users list to iterate over all the environments.

I have a command like below where i want to run the following combinations

"az role assignment {{ username }} {{ env }}"

az role assignment john dev

az role assignment john qa

az role assignment john uat  ...etc

Can you any one please help me

Comment: I wish there was <ban for code as image> button...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use nested loops:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_loops.html#nested-loops

```
- name: do command
  command: az role assignment {{item[0]}} {{item[1]}}
  with_nested:
   - - john
     - paul
   - - dev
     - qa
     - ua
```

Answer (score 0):

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    objs:
      - { key1: value1, key2: [ value2, value3] }
      - { key1: value4, key2: [ value5, value6] }
  tasks:

    - name: create directories
      file: path="{{ item.key1 }}"  state=directory
      with_items:
        objs

    - name: create files
      file: path="{{ item.0.key1 }}/{{ item.1 }}"  state=touch
      with_subelements:
        - objs
        - key2
```